# process should be repeatable, only insert new records or/and update existing records

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I created a table using this script.

```
use DWResourceTask
go
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[DimEntity]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [DimEntity]
Go
Create Table DimEntity

(EntityKey int NOT NULL identity PRIMARY KEY,
[EntCode] [nvarchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyRegistration] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [Active] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AccessLevel] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [SiteURN] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyURN] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [SiteName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [SiteDesc] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [SiteURL] [nvarchar](512) NOT NULL)
```

And I inserted data using this

```
Select e.EntCode, e.Name, e.Active, e.AccessLevel, ss.SiteURN, ss.CompanyURN,
ss.SiteName, ss.SiteDesc, ss.SiteURL
from USA.dbo.SCSite ss, USA.dbo.SCLegalEnt e
where ss.localsiteflag = 1
and e.active = 1
UNION ALL
Select e.EntCode, e.Name, e.Active, e.AccessLevel, ss.SiteURN, ss.CompanyURN,
ss.SiteName, ss.SiteDesc, ss.SiteURL
from UK.dbo.SCSite ss, UK.dbo.SCLegalEnt e
where ss.localsiteflag = 1
and e.active = 1
```

What I want to do is that I'm planning to create an SSIS package that no matter how many times I execute, it will only insert new records or/and update existing records. Process should be repeatable.

What script should I put in the SQL command in OLE DB source to insert "only" new records or/and update existing records.

Is it some sort of Update command? But how? I dont thin I need truncate or delete command to update the data in the table.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2008+ then check out the MERGE statement. That is what this is for.

Comment: Actually, *don't* use Merge. There are some serious defects in the [implementation](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/another-merge-bug)

Answer (score 3):

Your OLE DB Source command should be a query that identifies the candidate pool of records. If you can eliminate a range because you know it is invalid, apply a filter here. For example, you are only loading current year data then you'd apply a filter like `SELECT T.* FROM Country.dbo.Table AS T WHERE T.year = 2013` or you're loading last 30 days or whatever your source range could be.

This will allows rows to flow into your data flow. From there, you'd want to perform change detection on the available rows to your reference/destination set. Since you need to account for change rows, you'll probably need some criteria to determine what's changed versus what is used for match criteria. In our data warehouse, we have two hash keys: historical and change. Historical are the business keys hashed together via the HASHBYTES function while the change key are the non-business keys hashed together. In our first lookup, we test for the existence of the current row's historical hash and the change key to the reference set's. If both match, then I know the current row exists in my dataset and the values are the same so that gets routed to a row count and then off to the bit bucket.

In the no match output from the first lookup, I know either this is a brand new row or it's a change to an existing row. I'll need to perform a second lookup to determine which is true so add another Lookup Component, this time only matching on historical hash key. If I find a match, then I need to perform an update. Otherwise, I have a new row.

Unless your dataset is small, rather than using an OLE DB Command to perform an update, you will likely get better performance by staging your updates to a table and performing an Execute SQL Task after the Data Flow completes to actually perform the Update. The reason for this is that the OLE DB Command, not to be confused with OLE DB Destination, performs singleton database operations which is contrary to the set-based nature of proper ETL.

Andy Leonard has a great series, the [Stairway to Integration Services](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/), where he covers the Incremental load pattern in detail.

Comment: this is what I meant 

Lets say I run and I run this script below again and again.

Select e.EntCode, e.Name, e.Active, e.AccessLevel, ss.SiteURN, ss.CompanyURN,
ss.SiteName, ss.SiteDesc, ss.SiteURL
from USA.dbo.SCSite ss, USA.dbo.SCLegalEnt e
where ss.localsiteflag = 1
and e.active = 1
UNION ALL
Select e.EntCode, e.Name, e.Active, e.AccessLevel, ss.SiteURN, ss.CompanyURN,
ss.SiteName, ss.SiteDesc, ss.SiteURL
from UK.dbo.SCSite ss, UK.dbo.SCLegalEnt e
where ss.localsiteflag = 1
and e.active = 1

Comment: Hi @billinkc please disregard my comment on top.

I'd like a script where it inserts and inserts data no matter how many times I execute "or" manually run an Insert command into my DimEntity table without duplicating the data in my DimEntity table.

Comment: To restate your problem. You have a set of data in your source. The destination may have all of the data, none of the data or some subset of that data. You would like to have a process that synchronizes the data from source to the destination without introducing duplicates. The first `Lookup Transformation` above will test for key existence. The second provides change detection (source has AccessLevel 3, Destination has AccessLevel 2 ergo, update). Am I misunderstanding your problem? Otherwise, it looks like a standard type 1 dimension