# How can I insert again and again without duplicating the records inside the table I created?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the table I created:

```
use DWResourceTask
go
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[TESTDimEntity]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [TESTDimEntity]
Go
Create Table TESTDimEntity

(EntityKey int NOT NULL identity PRIMARY KEY,
[EntCode] [nvarchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyRegistration] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [Active] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AccessLevel] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [SiteURN] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyURN] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [SiteName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [SiteDesc] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [SiteURL] [nvarchar](512) NOT NULL)
```

---

And I inserted data using this script below:

```
Insert into DWResourceTask.dbo.TESTDimEntity
Select e.EntCode, e.Name, CompanyRegistration, e.Active, e.AccessLevel, ss.SiteURN, ss.CompanyURN,
ss.SiteName, ss.SiteDesc, ss.SiteURL
from USA.dbo.Site ss, USA.dbo.LegalEnt e
where ss.localsiteflag = 1
and e.active = 1
UNION ALL
Select e.EntCode, e.Name, CompanyRegistration, e.Active, e.AccessLevel, ss.SiteURN, ss.CompanyURN,
ss.SiteName, ss.SiteDesc, ss.SiteURL
from UK.dbo.Site ss, UK.dbo.LegalEnt e
where ss.localsiteflag = 1
and e.active = 1
```

and this script produced these 3 rows with each column have its own data.

---

My Question is..

What if I want to run the "Insert into script" over and over and it does not append nor duplicate the data but it only updates, only insert new records or/and update existing records.

Is there any script that would not insert the data's already present in the current `DimEntity` Table?

Many Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [process should be repeatable, only insert new records or/and update existing records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648948/process-should-be-repeatable-only-insert-new-records-or-and-update-existing-rec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).

```
WITH c as (
 SELECT ...
   FROM USA.dbo.Site ss 
   JOIN USA.dbo.LegalEnt e
     ON <somejoincondition here!>
   WHERE ss.localsiteflag = 1
      and e.active = 1
 UNION ALL ...)
MERGE INTO TESTDimEntity as t
 USING c
 ON (t.EntCode = c.EntCode)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
 SET t.<field> = c.<field>
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (t.<fields>)
  VALUES (c.<fields>);
```

There are some problems with your statement, the missing JOIN clause being the most obvious. You should have an index to enforce any expected UNIQUEness.