# Using a tsql MERGE statement in SSIS to copy data between databases

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl

I am trying to do something which I think should be very straightforward, but I can't see how to actually do it.

I have two databases which contain the same table with the same structure.

I want to import the data from one database into the other, inserting new rows where they don't exist and updating rows that match on id. This needs to be done every evening.

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I think the best way would be to use an SSIS package with an 'execute sql task' that contains a tsql MERGE statement.

I can't see how to actually do the two database connections the process would need.

I have looked a lot at books on-line, and although it says it is possible, have found no examples.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The TSQL Merge isn't going to accomplish this. Look at the [Incremental Load Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648948/process-should-be-repeatable-only-insert-new-records-or-and-update-existing-rec/19649355#19649355)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer billinkc. I followed the link and ended up at 'Andy Leonard has a great series, the Stairway to Integration Services, where he covers the Incremental load pattern in detail.' This was how I did this in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Incremental Load Pattern is the way to go for this problem.

See a great explanation and example at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/

I still think Merge would be a neater way to do it of you could provide the source and destination db.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using the Merge Transformation in SSIS. Regarding the connections, you can create 2 connection managers at package level. Then, add a Data Flow Task and pipe the output of both OLEDB sources to a Merge Transformation. Do ensure that the data is sorted before you do this, else there will be error.

Another option to explore is Replication. Based on your statement that this needs to be done every evening, you could create Snapshot replication, with one of your tables as the source and the other as target. On the other hand, if you want the data to go through in near real-time, or if both tables can be changed by an application or so, you could use Transactional Replication. More info on that on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152531.aspx)